# invalid console appender config detected, console stream is looping in Jboss 5.1

Tags: jboss

I am getting the below error in the JBoss console logs.

> Error:invalid console appender config detected, console stream is looping.

Tried changing the `JAVA_OPTS` as below but no effect.

```
 set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dprogram.name=%PROGNAME% -Dorg.jboss.logging.Log4jService.catchSystemOut=false
```

Comment: Could you share your log4j configuration?